# Как правильно реализовать вход в админку?

Tags: php, mvc

Делаю сайт для практики на mvc. Как правильно реализовать вход в админку? Что-то не могу сообразить.

Получаю я данные из формы админки, потом создаю из них объект, дальше, наверное, в модели нужно делать выборку всех данных пользователей из БД и потом сравнивать данные с теми, которые я преобразовал в объект. Правильно? или какая-то иная должна быть логика?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем выбирать все данные, если можно попросить БД выдать пользователя с введенным ником. Если вернет пустой ответ, значит пользователь ошибся. Если вернет строку, то взять оттуда пароль и сравнить... ну и так далее